# How to get correct attendee response statuses from an event with microsoft graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

So I've been playing around with the Microsoft Graph API and building an application that fetches and displays in some way the calendar data.

I seem to have encountered one inconsistency though, the response status of an attendee in the Event is always "none" regardless of what they actually responded. Even after accepting an invitation to an event if I query the events again they the status for my attendee entry is still "none", even though all other participants received an email saying that I accepted the invitation.

How can I get the correct (up-to-date) response status of attendees?

Comment: Please include a code sample showing how you're calling the API (both for creating the event and for checking the status).

Comment: Which instance of the appointment are you querying ? Only the organizer instance will have the responses so if your querying the instance stored in a Meeting room then null would be expected.

Comment: What is the "instance" of an appointment?
I did multiple tests, for example I create an event and invite someone else. The other person accepts the invite, still on my calendar it says that the invited person has not responded yet. This is not only via the API but also on the web client of the calendar

Comment: Hi @GlenScales is there a reason for that behavior? For me it's strange to have one more step to get just the attendee response. I don't think this is a sensitive iformation.

Comment: hi @Esser420, did you find any solution to get attendee response?